# How can i get current querying table id inside a relation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i have two tables
1 - Article
2 - Article Trans

one article have multiple article transes

Article is a model
ArticleTrans is another model

```
ArticleTrans::where('status',1)->with(['article'=>function($q){
    $q->with(['articleTrans'=>function($q){
        $q->where('id','Current Queryieng Id of Article Trans table')
   }])
}])
```

how can i do this ?
ArticleTrans is a relation between Article and article Trans

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Get ArticleTrans datas with article relationship, but what condition you want to apply?

Comment: Your goal iss a little bit vague can, what is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Relationship can be defined on the model class of each model which an be accessed on controller by `with` attribute on Eloquent ORM querying.

Write a relationship on your model as follows

```
class articleTrans{

    protected $fillable = ['articleTrans_auto_id', 'your other columns'];

    public class articleRf(){
       // import article class top the file
       // provide article class primary key
       // provide articleTrans primary key
       // it will fecth all the data which are related
       return $this->hasMany(article::class, 'id', 'articleTrans_auto_id');
    }

}
```

To get relationship data on you controller

```
public function index(){
    $object = articleTrans::with('articleRf')->where('status',1)->get();
   
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $object
    ]);
}
```